# Applying the tower rule to multiplications of functions of dependent normal random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

$
\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{cov}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\renewcommand{\endproof}{\quad_\square}
$
Suppose
$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \Sigma_{XX})$, 
$Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \Sigma_{YY})$,
$\cov[X,Y] = \Sigma_{XY}$.

Is it true that $\E_{X,Y}[X \cdot \sin{Y}] = \E_Y[\E_{X|Y}[X|Y]\cdot \sin{Y}]$? What about the more general case, $\E_{X,Y}[X \cdot f(Y)] = \E_Y[\E_{X|Y}[X|Y]\cdot f(Y)]$ for arbitrary $f$?

---

I can show that $\E_{X,Y}[X \cdot Y] = \E_Y[\E_{X|Y}[X|Y] \cdot Y]$:

> It is a standard result that $\E_{X,Y}[X \cdot Y] = \Sigma_{XY} + \mu_X \cdot \mu_Y$. 
>   From [this answer on stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/193027), we have that
>   $$\E_{X|Y}[X|Y] = \mu_X + \frac{\Sigma_{XY}}{\Sigma_{YY}}(Y - \mu_Y).$$
>   Now $$\begin{split}
> \E_Y[\E_{X|Y}[X|Y] \cdot Y] &= \E_Y[(\mu_X + \frac{\Sigma_{XY}}{\Sigma_{YY}}(Y - \mu_Y)) \cdot Y] \\
> &= \E_Y[\mu_X \cdot Y] + \frac{\Sigma_{XY}}{\Sigma_{YY}}\E_Y[Y^2 - \mu_Y \cdot Y]\\
> &=\mu_x \cdot \mu_Y + \frac{\Sigma_{XY}}{\Sigma_{YY}}(\E_Y[Y^2] - \E_y[Y]^2) \\
> &=\mu_x \cdot \mu_Y + \frac{\Sigma_{XY}}{\Sigma_{YY}}\Sigma_{YY} \\
> &=\Sigma_{XY} + \mu_X \cdot \mu_Y = E_{X,Y}[XY]. \endproof
> \end{split}.$$

I am also aware of the tower rule $\E_X[X] = \E_Y[\E_{X|Y}[X|Y]]$, and I can sketch a proof along the lines of

> $$\begin{split}
> \E_{X,Y}[X \cdot f(Y)] &= \E_Y[\E_X[X \cdot f(Y)]] \\
>                        &= \E_Y[\E_X[X] \cdot f(Y)] \\
>                        &= \E_Y[\E_Y[\E_{X|Y}[X|Y]] \cdot f(Y)] \\
>                        &= \E_Y[\E_{X|Y}[X|Y]] \cdot \E_Y[f(Y)] \\
>                        &=\ \dots\ ?            
> \end{split}$$

But this is clearly wrong, since $\E_{X,Y}[X\cdot Y] \neq \E_X[X]\cdot \E_Y[Y]$ as the above would imply.

Comment: The result is entirely general and not specific to normal random variables: for every $(X,Y)$ suitably integrable, $$E(Xf(Y)\mid Y)=E(X\mid Y)f(Y)$$ hence $$E(Xf(Y))=E(E(Xf(Y)\mid Y))=E(E(X\mid Y)f(Y))$$

Comment: Re the try in your post, in the double identity, $$E_{X,Y}[X \cdot f(Y)]= E_Y[E_X[X \cdot f(Y)]]=E_Y[E_X[X] \cdot f(Y)]$$  I have no idea what $E_{X,Y}$, $E_X$ and $E_Y$ can mean but I suspect that $$E_{X,Y}(Z)=E_Y(E_X(Z))$$ is quite wrong in general, and I have no idea where $$E_X[X \cdot f(Y)]]=E_X[X] \cdot f(Y)$$ is coming from either, but I suspect it is quite wrong as well. Actually, I know of **no** situation where using the notations $E_{X,Y}$, $E_X$ and $E_Y$, instead of $E$, $E$ and $E$, is anything but harmful...

Comment: Hmm, and $E_{X\mid Y}$ is of the same ilk, only possibly even worse... :-)